# Add value to variable declared in TypeScript by ngfor in html

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ngfor

I declared variable in my ts file and in html file I'm using ngfor and I need to increase variable declared in ts by each element from ngfor is it possible?

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of invoiceItems">
    <td>{{item.ItemName}}</td>
    <td>{{item.ItemNetPrice}}</td>
    <td>{{item.ItemAmount}}</td>
    <td>{{item.ItemName}}</td>
    <td>{{item.ItemVATRate}}</td>
    <td>{{item.ItemName}}</td>
    <td>{{item.ItemName}}</td>
    <td>{{item.ItemName}}</td>
    <td>{{item.ItemName}}</td>
    <td>{{item.ItemName}}</td>
    {{netto += item.ItemNetPrice}}
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

netto is my variable

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: Do you want to add to the variable the number of elements in your collection?

Comment: I want add some value from all elements in my collection

Comment: It's probably better to handle that in the `subscribe` callback for the `invoiceItems` API request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your html like below

```
    <div *ngFor ="let item of invoiceItems; let i = index">
    <td>{{item.ItemName}}</td>
    <td>{{item.ItemNetPrice}}</td>
    <td>{{item.ItemAmount}}</td>
    <td>{{item.ItemName}}</td>
    <td>{{item.ItemVATRate}}</td>
    <td>{{item.ItemName}}</td>
    <td>{{item.ItemName}}</td>
    <td>{{item.ItemName}}</td>
    <td>{{item.ItemName}}</td>
    <td>{{item.ItemName}}</td>
    {{getTotal(i)}}
     </div>
```

and create getTotal method in your typescript file as below

```
getTotal(i) {
return this.invoiceItems.slice(0,i +1).map(rec => rec. ItemNetPrice).reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr, 0);
}
```